# Javascript opener object different in Chrome and IE when using top.window.open()

Tags: javascript, popup, window.opener

I have a window named "MainApplication" that contains a frame named "Tabs".  "Tabs" loads a javascript page that opens a popup window.  When the popup window is opened it uses top.window.open().  So "MainApplication" should be opening a new popup since "Tabs" was the frame from which it was called, and "Tabs" is referencing the top.window object to open the popup.

When I obtain a reference to the newly opened window from open(), the opener object in Chrome displays the name as "Tabs".  However when I look at the window.opener object from a frame inside the actual window, Chrome displays the name as "MainApplication".

In IE11, the value displayed within the reference to the new window as the opener is "Tabs".  When I display the opener value in the newly created window, IE also displays this as "Tabs" (even though top.window was used to open the popup).

I wanted to create a JsFiddle to test outside of the application but I'm not sure how to create an alert within a new popup in JsFiddle.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<frame name="Tabs">
// from mainWindow.js
function openPopup() {
  var newWindow = top.window.open( ..,..,..,.. );
  alert( newWindow.opener.name );
}
</frame>
```

In the popup window:

```
<frame name="report">
// from inside the new popup, newWindow.js
function load() {
  alert( top.window.opener.name );
}
</frame>
```

I need to be able to access the "Tabs" frame from the newly created popup window and I'm not sure how.  "Tabs" might not always be the frame that opened the popup and I also have to use top.window.open() because "MainApplication" contains needed vars.

I suppose I could just ask how to access a child frame in the opener that created a new popup, but I'm also curious if anyone has run into this and found a cross-browser compatible solution (specifically in why the values in the reference to the new window are different than the values in the actual window).

Comment: from the popup, you want just `opener.name`

Comment: I get an error saying opener is null when I just use opener.name, same with window.opener.name, I assumed it was because it's being called from within a frame so wouldn't I have to use top.window.opener?

Comment: well, if opener is null from the popup, then you can't reach the other stuff at all. just know that from the popup, `opener` is the same as `top` is from the frame...